# reachability best practice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, cocoa

My app pulls a json data feed , I have just added the reachability check in to the applicationDidBecomeActive in the app delegate . If the network is contactable then the viewcontroller is loaded. From the view controller the parser class gets called which populates a UITableview. 
If the network is non-contactable it displays an alert. If the user presses the home button activates the wireless or cellular data and then returns to the app the viewcontroller gets loaded. Whilst this works the solution isn't particularly elegant as each time the user returns to the app after placing in the background the viewcontroller calls are run through again. I wonder if there any better alternatives?

AppDelegate.m

```
  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

// Check for network connectivity

reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:@"App cannot connect to the internet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    self.internetActive = NO;
}


else {

    NSLog(@"internet available");
    self.internetActive = YES;

}


// if internet available call viewcontroller;

if (self.internetActive) {
    navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewController];
    [window addSubview:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
else {
    //error pic background display
}
```

And then the viewcontroller.m

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {

UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; 
[loadingActivityIndicator startAnimating];

Infoparser *cparser = [[FCO_parser alloc] init];
[cparser queryclistwithViewCont:self];
[cparser release];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the viewDidLoad method is actually called? NSLog(@"VC called");     I'm not sure what you're trying to optimize, since your views have to be loaded when the app wakes up anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your existing reachability check is almost certain to return false negative results. Reachability does a good job of telling you when a network connection is certainly *not* available or when a connection *might* be available but not that a connection *is* available or that a request will succeed.

Suppose a user only has access to a WWAN network and their network interface is currently inactive. You create a new Reachability instance, start requesting reachability notifications, and immediately check `-currentReachabilityStatus`. This will return `NotReachable` until several seconds later when the WWAN interface finally comes online.

Instead I suggest you think about this problem differently and separate your display of data from the process of fetching it.

When your view appears display whatever version of this json feed you have or an appropriate message if you do not yet have any data.

When your app becomes active (or on some other appropriate event) attempt to fetch a new copy of the data feed. If this attempt fails then subscribe to `reachabilityChanged` notifications and try again when Reachability indicates that a network connection *might* now be available. Repeat until you successfully fetch data and update your view when you do.

You can then cache the current version of the data feed and display it until you get a more up to date version. If you save a timestamp of when you last successfully updated the feed you can even choose to discard it if it becomes sufficiently out of date or show the user how old their view of the feed currently is.

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion is not to halt loading of your initial view but, instead, let the view load and handle the potential lack of a network connection appropriately.

As far as displaying messages to the user, I would still leave that in the appDelegate as a central location.  From there, you could display a modal view controller with the message / image.  This could be added to the window and thus be set on top of anything currently visible to the user.

Just my 2 cents...